# i dont' know why my for loop isn't returning anything

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

i dont' know why my for loop isn't returning anything#table tame is the table from sql, it should return each item from the sql table in the format below.

```
def count_columns(table_name):
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM " + table_name)
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        if len(row) == "2":
            print("ID: ", row,[0], "Category: ", row[1])
        elif len(row) == "3":
            print("ID: ", row,[0], "Range: ", row[1], "Category: ", row[2])
        elif len(row) == "4":
            print("ID: ", row,[0], "Systolic: ", row[1], "Diastolic: ", row[2], "Category: ", row[3])
```

Comment: len? is that length?

Comment: yes, its meant to calculate the length of items in the table row (from the databse)